# Get featured image of post and link rel="preload" as="image" in wp-head

Tags: wordpress

I have a code to put it in fuction.php. The code is working well. See below

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
$featured_img_url = get_post_thumbnail_or_first_img('et-pb-image--responsive--phone'); 
echo '<link rel="preload" as="image" href="'.$featured_img_url.'"/>';
});
```

Currently, it is adding to header.php on entire website. But I want it to add in header.php only on archive pages and home page(set as latest post view).

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [built-in functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) to check what kind of page is it. Untested but should work.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){

  //Checks is this page archive page
  if( is_archive() ) {
  
    $featured_img_url = get_post_thumbnail_or_first_img('et-pb-image--responsive--phone'); 
    echo '<link rel="preload" as="image" href="'.$featured_img_url.'"/>';
    
  }
  
});
```

Comment: Thank worked. i added home page too 

if( is_archive() || is_home() )  {

Now it is complete. Thank You